# Azure functions: Trying to get VM list and getting an error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to add in Azure function tag for all of the VM's in the current subscription.
but i get this error:

2023-06-11T19:15:34Z   [Information]   11111

2023-06-11T19:15:34Z   [Information]   22222

2023-06-11T19:15:34Z   [Error]   **An error occurred while updating VM tags:System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'MSI_ENDPOINT')**
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication.MSITokenProvider.GetAuthenticationHeaderForAppServiceAsync(String resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

This is my code, I'm not sure I made the authentication correct the VM's are in the same same subscription as the function.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity(MSIResourceType.AppService, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            ComputeManager.Authenticate(credentials, "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA");

            log.LogInformation($"11111");

            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithSubscription("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA");

            log.LogInformation($"22222");

            var virtualMachines = azure.VirtualMachines.ListByResourceGroup("MYResGroup");
```

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable MSI on the service?

Answer (score 0):

- You're using the `SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity` method to authenticate with a system-assigned managed identity. However, this method is part of the Azure SDK for Java, not for .NET.

I've updated the code to use the `Azure.Identity` library for authentication:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[FunctionName("UpdateVMTags")]
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
    ILogger log)
{
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    var subscriptionId = "YourSubscriptionId";

    var computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential)
    {
        SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
    };

    log.LogInformation("11111");

    var virtualMachines = await computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.ListAllAsync();

    foreach (var virtualMachine in virtualMachines)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"VM Name: {virtualMachine.Name}");
        // Perform operations on the virtual machine, such as updating tags
    }

    log.LogInformation("22222");
}
```

- I've replaced `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` with `Azure.Identity` for authentication. The `DefaultAzureCredential` class is used to authenticate using the available credentials based on the environment (including MSI when running in Azure). I've also changed `ListByResourceGroupAsync` to `ListAllAsync` to retrieve all virtual machines across the subscription.

[image]

- Enable the managed identity, then update the VM tags again. try using a user-assigned managed identity instead of a system-assigned one because it provides more control and flexibility over the identity and its permissions.

Refer this document [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support.md) for Azure resources tags.

Comment: are you sure i should use Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication and not Azure identity? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/app-auth-migration?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Great to hear @user3879322, as per the above MS document. we can use both libraries `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication`. It simplifies the process of obtaining access tokens for Azure services by providing a straightforward API. Whereas `Azure.Identity` is a comprehensive authentication library that provides wide range of authentication methods and a unified API for authenticating to Azure services across different scenarios and platforms. I have updated the code please check it out in the answer.

Comment: var computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential)
row does not compile...